# CanCan: load_and_authorize_resource in namespace other than that of MainApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, cancan, rails-engines

I'm using CanCan for permissions in my Rails application in which I have built my own engine for some generic form functionality. I would like to lock down permissions in my system so that users cannot freely access my engine controllers' actions. These controllers, for the most part, just make use of the 7 REST actions, so I would like to use CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of each controller.

However, when I write my code like this:

```
    module MyEngine
      class FormController < ApplicationController
        load_and_authorize_resource
        ...
      end
    end
```

I get this error:

```
    uninitialized constant Form
```

My guess is that the automatic loader in `load_and_authorize_resource` is tied to my MainApp namespace, and does not recognize that I am calling it in a different namespace, and so does a call like `Form.find(params[:id])` rather than `MyEngine::Form.find(params[:id])`.

If this is the case, how can I fix this? It's not a huge deal because `authorize!` still works properly, so I can define the authorization in each action individually, but it would feel much cleaner if I were able to use the `load_and_authorize_resource` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorizing Namespaced and Nested controllers using CanCan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334367/authorizing-namespaced-and-nested-controllers-using-cancan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in `CanCan::ControllerResource#namespace`:

```
def namespace
  @params[:controller].split("::")[0..-2]
end
```

As you see, it tries to split controller path by `::` but it comes in the form of `my_engine/my_controller`.

So the fix is dumb simple:

```
def namespace
  @params[:controller].split("/")[0..-2]
end
```

Wonder how they could miss such a stupid bug for so long. Shall send them a pull request.

P.S. Have just signed up to answer 8)

Comment: Oh! It's even more interesting: they seem to just forget merging the fix to `master` branch.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/663

Comment: Nice one, this was just what I needed!

Comment: A patch for this was applied [in 1.6.10](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/675)

Answer (score 9):

CanCan can not find namespaced models. Try to specify class:

```
load_and_authorize_resource class: MyEngine::Form
```

Answer (score 3):

If the model class is namespaced differently than the controller, you will need to specify the `:class` option.

```
module MyEngine
  class FormController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :class => MyEngine::Form
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `uninitialized constant MyEngine::Form` for this.